# Countdown timer looping - NEW ERROR

Tags: java, android-studio, timer

As shown in the code below, I have two timers. The 18 second one is meant to run for longer, but I keep it short for testing purposes. My intention is for the 4 second timer to repeat after the user enters their input, BUT I want it to repeat with loadG1 being outputted again. So it ends for the first time, then is repeated after the user presses enter and starts again but with loadG1 being outputted first. Obviously this would be difficult, because number (and therefore loadG1) disappears right at the beginning of the timer. How could I go about doing this? Would I need another timer?

```
final Button loseStarter1;

    loseStarter1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Starter1);
    loseStarter1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            loseStarter1.setVisibility(View.GONE);

            final int[] score = {0};
            Random generateG1 = new Random();
            final int loadG1 = generateG1.nextInt(1000000)+10000;
            final TextView number = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.number);
            number.setText(" "+loadG1);

            new CountDownTimer(4000, 1000) {
                @Override
                public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                }
                public void onFinish() {
                    number.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    final TextView prompt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.prompt);
                    prompt.setText(" Enter the number");
                    final EditText input = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.enterAnswer);
                    input.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    input.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {
                        @Override
                        public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
                        if (event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
                            switch (keyCode){
                                case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER:
                                    Editable answer = input.getText();
                                    int finalAnswer = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(answer));
                                    int finalLoadG1 = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(loadG1));
                                    input.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                    prompt.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                    if (finalAnswer==finalLoadG1){
                                        score[0]++;
                                    }
                                    return true;
                                default:
                                    break;
                            }
                        }
                            return false;
                        }
                    });
                }
            }.start();

            new CountDownTimer(18000, 1000) {
                @Override
                public void onTick (long millisUntilFinished) {
                }
                public void onFinish() {
                    TextView result = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.outcome);
                    result.setText("Score: "+ score[0]);
                    TextView prompt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.prompt);
                    prompt.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
            }.start();

            }
        });
```

To make things slightly more complicated, I would like the longer (18 sec) timer to be paused whenever the 4 second one is running. So as long as loadG1 is visible, I'd like the long timer to be paused. When the 4 sec timer ends and the user can input a value (answer), I would like the longer timer to continue. Right now, this timer starts from the beginning. Note: LoadG1 is first outputted when button is pressed and 4 seconds starts then.

Would greatly appreciate all support in this.

EDIT: I have attempted a loop which I believe would work, though my application freezes. I get told my app is 'not responding' and the emulator freezes. Here is the extra part I added shown in my code:

```
int n = 1;
            while (n < 2) {
                new CountDownTimer(4000, 1000) {
                    @Override
                    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                    }

                    public void onFinish() {
                        number.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        final TextView prompt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.prompt);
                        prompt.setText(" Enter the number");
                        final EditText input = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.enterAnswer);
                        input.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        input.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {
                            @Override
                            public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
                                if (event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                                    switch (keyCode) {
                                        case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER:
                                            Editable answer = input.getText();
                                            int finalAnswer = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(answer));
                                            int finalLoadG1 = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(loadG1));
                                            input.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                            prompt.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                            if (finalAnswer == finalLoadG1) {
                                                score[0]++;
                                            }

                                            return true;
                                        default:
                                            break;
                                    }
                                }
                                return false;
                            }
                        });

                        number.setText(" " + loadG1);
                    }
                }.start();
            }
```

EDIT 2: Same error with different code...
    final Button loseStarter1;

```
    loseStarter1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Starter1);
    loseStarter1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            loseStarter1.setVisibility(View.GONE);

            final int[] score = {0};
            Random generateG1 = new Random();
            final int loadG1 = generateG1.nextInt(1000000)+10000;
            final TextView number = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.number);
            number.setText(" "+loadG1);

            new CountDownTimer(18000, 1000) {
                @Override
                public void onTick (long millisUntilFinished) {
                }
                public void onFinish() {
                    TextView result = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.outcome);
                    result.setText("Score: "+ score[0]);
                    TextView prompt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.prompt);
                    prompt.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
            }.start();

               while (true) {
                   SystemClock.sleep(4000);
                   number.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                   final TextView prompt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.prompt);
                   prompt.setText(" Enter the number");
                   final EditText input = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.enterAnswer);
                   input.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                   input.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {
                       @Override
                       public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
                           if (event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                               switch (keyCode) {
                                   case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER:
                                       Editable answer = input.getText();
                                       int finalAnswer = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(answer));
                                       int finalLoadG1 = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(loadG1));
                                       input.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                       prompt.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                       if (finalAnswer == finalLoadG1) {
                                           score[0]++;
                                       }

                                       return true;
                                   default:
                                       break;
                               }
                           }
                           return false;
                       }
                   });
               }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could have something like :

```
    while(true)
    {
    // 18 minute timer.pause -> not too sure about this one. 
    // get input
    // show output
    wait(4 seconds) -> you could use thread.sleep(4000) here
    }
```

Edit: 
I mean something like this:

```
 while (true) {
               // Function that manipulates and accepts values
               Function(parameters)        
               number.setText(" " + loadG1);
               thread.sleep(4000);
               }
```

Comment: I followed your suggestion about the loop, see edited question.

Comment: Your edited code looks like, you are trying to start a timer which runs every 4 seconds, every time the code enters the while loop (which in this case would be every few mili seconds.) I believe it goes into an endless loop (freezes) and hence your program stops responding.

Comment: So I am not well versed with android programming but I am guessing you would have something like a thread.sleep method which would stop the current thread for a given amount of time. Could you not request for input value and set your values, and then make the thread sleep for 4 seconds? That should work the same way as a 4 seconds timer which is run right after it executes your input and set code.

Comment: Your explanation on freezing makes sense, I can see why that happens. Are you suggesting I get rid of the countdown timer and put everything in a while true loop with a 4 sec sleep at the end instead?

Comment: Yes, exactly. The 4 second thread sleep will act like a timer.

Comment: I did this with confidence it would work, but I get the same error about my app not responding. Something to do with loop? Please see new edit for modified code.

Comment: Did you try debugging to check at which point it freezes? Also, could you remove the 18 second timer and try testing this part of the code once?

Comment: Your suggestions made no difference.

Comment: This has been resolved, thank you for your contribution. Although your post was not the resolution, I will mark it as the answer. I appreciate your time.

Comment: Thank you. What really helped resolve the issue (just curious)?

Comment: See the following link, I answered it myself there: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40057754/how-can-i-repeat-this-countdown-timer-in-a-specific-way?noredirect=1#comment67397696_40057754