# How can I repeat this countdown timer in a specific way...?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, countdowntimer

In the game a random number (loadG1) outputted and is shown for 4 seconds. Once the four seconds are up, it disappears and the user must input its value to gain a point. Once the user presses enter, their input box disappears and the program must wait until the longer CountDownTimer (currently 18 seconds) has ended to see their score. So far, they can only score one point. What I want to happen is for the contents of the 4 second countdowntimer to be repeated once they enter an answer (whether correct or not). Although, I want loadG1 to also be outputted when they countdown timer starts again. So they enter an answer, a new random loadG1 is shown for another 4 secs then disappears, they enter another answer, etc... until the longer timer ends. How would I go about doing this? I'm aware that loops don't work, as I tried and it just crashed my app. I'd be very grateful if someone could help me do this, and show me how to implement the code.
NOTE: I am new to learning Java and Android dev.
Many thanks in advance.

Here's the code:

```
public class game1 extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_game1);


final Button loseStarter1;

    loseStarter1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Starter1);
    loseStarter1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            loseStarter1.setVisibility(View.GONE);

            final int[] score = {0};
            Random generateG1 = new Random();
            final int loadG1 = generateG1.nextInt(1000000)+10000;
            final TextView number = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.number);
            number.setText(" "+loadG1);

            new CountDownTimer(18000, 1000) {
                @Override
                public void onTick (long millisUntilFinished) {
                }
                public void onFinish() {
                    TextView result = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.outcome);
                    result.setText("Score: "+ score[0]);
                    TextView prompt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.prompt);
                    prompt.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
            }.start();


                    new CountDownTimer(4000, 1000) {

                        @Override
                        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {

                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onFinish() {
                            number.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            final TextView prompt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.prompt);
                            prompt.setText(" Enter the number");
                            final EditText input = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.enterAnswer);
                            input.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            input.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {
                                @Override
                                public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
                                    if (event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                                        switch (keyCode) {
                                            case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER:
                                                Editable answer = input.getText();
                                                int finalAnswer = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(answer));
                                                int finalLoadG1 = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(loadG1));
                                                input.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                                prompt.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                                if (finalAnswer == finalLoadG1) {
                                                    score[0]++;
                                                }

                                                return true;
                                            default:
                                        }
                                    }
                                    return false;
                                }
                            });
                        }
                    }.start();

            };
        });
    }

}
```

Comment: You should try and rephrase this question. It's quite hard understanding what you want to achieve.

Comment: @UdiIdan What is it you don't understand? The way I read it, it seems to make sense. I'd happily edit in any addition information you require.

Comment: If you need an answer you should make an effort phrasing the question so it would be easy to understand. It should make sense to the readers, rather than to you. Good luck.

Comment: @UdiIdan If you actually read it and skimmed the code, it would make perfect sense.

Comment: That's great. Maybe you should answer it. I wrote the comment trying to be helpful so you'll get an answer, but if you feel the question is good, that's fine too.

Comment: @UdiIdan Sorry for the late response, took me a while to get over how funny your joke was. My first comment consisted of me asking you how I could specify my situation, you failed to inform me on how to do so, so I'm not so sure what you expect.

Comment: And yet eventually you are the only one answered the question.  Surprising, I have to say. If you are trying to learn, as you’ve stated, that’s not the way to go. Let’s stop this discussion as obviously it’s not productive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**RESOLVED**

I put the following after the score[0]++:

```
number.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
final int loadG1 = generateG1.nextInt(1000000) + 10000;
number.setText(" " + loadG1);
input.getText().clear();

start();
```

This way, all necessary changes are made and the timer begins anew. I also modified the visibility of the *prompt* TextView to ensure it only appear when the user is able to input an answer. Took me a while but this has been resolved.