# Score not updating in Countdown Timer repeat

Tags: java, android, countdowntimer

In this game, the user scores a point for every time they input an integer equal to a random number generated (variable called 'LoadG1'). If their input == loadG1, they get a point added to the 'score' variable. The idea is it should increase by one point every time they answer it correctly, but for some reason they can score no more than one point. If one question is correct, they get a point which is displayed at the end. Any more correct answers are ignored.

Here's the code:

```
final int[] score = {0};
final Random generateG1 = new Random();
final int loadG1 = generateG1.nextInt(1000000)+10000;
final TextView number = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.number);
number.setText(" "+loadG1);


    final CountDownTimer loop = new CountDownTimer(4000, 1000) {
    @Override
    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
    }
    @Override
    public void onFinish() {
        number.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        final TextView prompt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.prompt);
        prompt.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        prompt.setText(" Enter the number");
        final EditText input = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.enterAnswer);
        input.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        input.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
                if (event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                    switch (keyCode) {
                        case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER:
                            Editable answer = input.getText();
                            int finalAnswer = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(answer));
                            int finalLoadG1 = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(loadG1));
                            input.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            prompt.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            if (finalAnswer == finalLoadG1) {
                                score[0]++;
                            }

                            number.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            final int loadG1 = generateG1.nextInt(1000000) + 10000;
                            number.setText(" " + loadG1);
                            input.getText().clear();

                            start();

                            return true;
                        default:
                    }
                }
                return false;
            }
        });
    }
    }.start();

    new CountDownTimer(24000, 1000) {
    @Override
    public void onTick (long millisUntilFinished) {
    }
    @Override
    public void onFinish() {
        TextView result = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.outcome);
        result.setText("Score: "+ score[0]);
        TextView prompt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.prompt);
        prompt.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        final EditText input = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.enterAnswer);
        input.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        loop.cancel();
    }
}.start();
```

The score variable is declared before either timer, then a point is added in the short 4 sec timer, and printed at the end of the longer timer. All is shown in the code above.

I'd be grateful if anyone could help me ensure that the score counter is updated for each time they enter the correct answer, thanks in advance.

Comment: Why all yor variables are `final`?

Comment: @Kacper The IDE requires a lot of them to be for my program to compile successfully.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I repeat this countdown timer in a specific way...?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40057754/how-can-i-repeat-this-countdown-timer-in-a-specific-way)

Answer (score 0):

Remove `final` modifier before score definition and I believe this will help.

Comment: I'm afraid I can't do that. If you examine my code, you'd see that the score variable is used in two different countdown timers. Without it being final, I can't use it this way.

Comment: But final means you can modify variable only once. This is why it is 1 never more.

Comment: I'm aware, but removing final complicates my situation in the sense that I cannot then call variable in a different method (or Countdown Timer in my case).

Comment: Just create private global variable (synchronised if many threads can access) and getter method to access from other places. @User44