# Score variable won't update, and must be final?

Tags: java, android, final, countdowntimer

The issue I'm having is that my score counter variable 'score' cannot go higher than 1 in my program. If the user inputs a value equal to the random number displayed (LoadG1), they are awarded a point. This is then outputted at the end, as shown in the longer timer. In the shorter timer, the point is added. The int variable is declared at the beginning. All is shown below. Now I'm aware that it's final, and that this is most likely the cause of my issue, but the IDE requires it to be final otherwise I can only call the variable 'score' in one method (CountDown Timer in my case). This is causing me problems. I intend to have a point added each time the 4 second timer repeats if the user has the correct input each time, though it can't go more than 1 at the moment. I would like the final score to be outputted at the end, as shown below.

The code:

```
final int[] score = {0};
final Random generateG1 = new Random();
final int loadG1 = generateG1.nextInt(1000000)+10000;
final TextView number = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.number);
number.setText(" "+loadG1);

final CountDownTimer loop = new CountDownTimer(4000, 1000) {
@Override
public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
}
@Override
public void onFinish() {
    number.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    final TextView prompt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.prompt);
    prompt.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    prompt.setText(" Enter the number");
    final EditText input = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.enterAnswer);
    input.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    input.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
            if (event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                switch (keyCode) {
                    case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER:
                        Editable answer = input.getText();
                        int finalAnswer = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(answer));
                        int finalLoadG1 = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(loadG1));
                        input.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        prompt.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        if (finalAnswer == finalLoadG1) {
                            score[0]++;
                        }

                        number.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        final int loadG1 = generateG1.nextInt(1000000) + 10000;
                        number.setText(" " + loadG1);
                        input.getText().clear();

                        start();

                        return true;
                    default:
                }
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
}
}.start();

new CountDownTimer(24000, 1000) {
@Override
public void onTick (long millisUntilFinished) {
}
@Override
public void onFinish() {
    TextView result = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.outcome);
    result.setText("Score: "+ score[0]);
    TextView prompt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.prompt);
    prompt.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    final EditText input = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.enterAnswer);
    input.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    loop.cancel();
}
}.start();
```

I'd greatly appreciate it if someone can provide me with a fix to my issue, thanks in advance.

Comment: Try coming up with a minimal viable example. I am not sure where your problem is. It is *fine* to have a *final* array - that just means the *array* itself will stay the same, but the one entry within that array can still be updated.

Comment: Can't you just make `score` a member variable of your class?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I repeat this countdown timer in a specific way...?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40057754/how-can-i-repeat-this-countdown-timer-in-a-specific-way)

Comment: look at my answer, it should help you, I've spotted your problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you are not reading the random value that you have generated, just the first one. So the first time the answer is correct, but next time you answer different, but the `if` compares to the firstly generated random number, so it is not counting as valid answer (if you enter same first number all times it will count). You need to read the number from the TextEdit number every time since there is the current number.

So it could be:

```
final int[] score = {0};
final Random generateG1 = new Random();
final int loadG1 = generateG1.nextInt(1000000)+10000;
final TextView number = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.number);
number.setText(" "+loadG1);

final CountDownTimer loop = new CountDownTimer(4000, 1000) {
@Override
public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
}
@Override
public void onFinish() {
    number.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    final TextView prompt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.prompt);
    prompt.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    prompt.setText(" Enter the number");
    final EditText input = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.enterAnswer);
    input.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    input.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
            if (event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                switch (keyCode) {
                    case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER:
                        Editable answer = input.getText();
                        int finalAnswer = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(answer));
                        // here we get from text field the current correct value
                        int finalLoadG1 = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(number.getText()));
                        input.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        prompt.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        if (finalAnswer == finalLoadG1) {
                            score[0]++;
                        }

                        number.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        final int loadG1 = generateG1.nextInt(1000000) + 10000;
                        number.setText(" " + loadG1);
                        input.getText().clear();

                        start();

                        return true;
                    default:
                }
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
}
}.start();

new CountDownTimer(24000, 1000) {
@Override
public void onTick (long millisUntilFinished) {
}
@Override
public void onFinish() {
    TextView result = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.outcome);
    result.setText("Score: "+ score[0]);
    TextView prompt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.prompt);
    prompt.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    final EditText input = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.enterAnswer);
    input.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    loop.cancel();
}
}.start();
```

Also, you could (and should) use AtomicInteger instead of `int[]`, the methods you'll be interested are:

```
int AtomicInteger#get();
int AtomicInteger#incrementAndGet()
```

So declare the score as AtomicInteger like:

```
final AtomicInteger score = new AtomicInteger();
```

then instead of `score[0]++;` do `score.incrementAndGet();`

then when you read the results do: `score.get();`

Comment: I modified it with your suggestion. It didn't work initially, so I got rid of the " " space before 'loadG1' and it now works. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Did you write `final int[] score = {0};` in the `onCreate`?

Try to write `int[] score = {0};` out of `onCreate`, as a global variable.